# c# wpf application with acrobat reader, when install on other machine cannot open pdf even if adobe reader is installed on machine

Tags: wpf, pdf, deployment

I am using acrobat reader in my c# wpf application to read pdf.It is working fine on my machine but when I install application on another machine, pdf not opens although adobe reader is installd on the machine.Please help me.Thanks in advance

Comment: This happens because of a different versions. Are you using the same version?

Comment: I have used Adobe PDF Reader v 1.0 as component and on my system I am having Adobe reader 10.1.0 installed,but I think it not depends on the version of pdf installed on machine

Comment: Yes it is a problem of version mismatch,I got it and code is now running on client machine also, thanks a lotttttt  Erti-Chris Eelmaa for your reply

Answer (score -1):

The problem is when you compile the Project...

checks in the document properties from Visual Studio , **always** copy the directory and compile the action is **Content**